# Apache nifi connection issue

Tags: sql-server, database, apache, networking, apache-nifi

[after doing netstat in my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwtg9.png) When i am trying to connect my DB with nifi is shows this error while when i am connecting through the same server it get's connected i have seen through 3 same servers where nifi is installed password db dbuser ip address port every things has been check many times. 
Can anyone help me with issue

> 2017-11-20 09:26:16,477 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.p.standard.GenerateTableFetch GenerateTableFetch[id=c9425209-015f-1000-003d-d071438865bd] GenerateTableFetch[id=c9425209-015f-1000-003d-d071438865bd] failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.; processor will not be scheduled to run for 30 seconds: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1480)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.access$000(StandardProcessorNode.java:102)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1301)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1463)
>       ... 9 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1301)
>       ... 6 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'abc'. ClientConnectionId:889f12ff-52d1-487e-9ac1-02b66eeaefe3)
>       at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:275)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor500.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:89)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractDatabaseFetchProcessor.setup(AbstractDatabaseFetchProcessor.java:228)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch.setup(GenerateTableFetch.java:159)
>       ... 15 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'abc'. ClientConnectionId:889f12ff-52d1-487e-9ac1-02b66eeaefe3)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>       at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:272)
>       ... 22 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'abc'. ClientConnectionId:889f12ff-52d1-487e-9ac1-02b66eeaefe3
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4346)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>       ... 25 common frames omitted
>   2017-11-20 09:26:16,478 ERROR [StandardProcessScheduler Thread-1] o.a.n.controller.StandardProcessorNode Failed to invoke @OnScheduled method due to java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed while executing one of processor's OnScheduled task.
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1480)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.access$000(StandardProcessorNode.java:102)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1.run(StandardProcessorNode.java:1301)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.invokeTaskAsCancelableFuture(StandardProcessorNode.java:1463)
>       ... 9 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor499.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotations(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
>       at org.apache.nifi.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodsWithAnnotation(ReflectionUtils.java:47)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode$1$1.call(StandardProcessorNode.java:1301)
>       ... 6 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'abc'. ClientConnectionId:889f12ff-52d1-487e-9ac1-02b66eeaefe3)
>       at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:275)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor500.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:89)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AbstractDatabaseFetchProcessor.setup(AbstractDatabaseFetchProcessor.java:228)
>       at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch.setup(GenerateTableFetch.java:159)
>       ... 15 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login failed for user 'abc'. ClientConnectionId:889f12ff-52d1-487e-9ac1-02b66eeaefe3)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
>       at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:272)
>       ... 22 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'abc'. ClientConnectionId:889f12ff-52d1-487e-9ac1-02b66eeaefe3
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:279)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:99)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4346)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1981)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1628)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1459)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:773)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1168)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
>       ... 25 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the relevant part of the stack trace is "Login failed for user 'abc'." If not an invalid password, perhaps the DB won't let you connect from your NiFi node? Sometimes DBs only allow connections from certain nodes, or certain users from certain nodes, etc.

Comment: i have installed several instances of nifi that are connecting with the same server just different connections there they are working fine but for only one particular connection nifi is giving error.

Comment: nifi takes only 8 characters in password and when i was setting 10 character password it was truncating the password by itself without any warning message got the issue resolved it.